# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser find LI elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Got structure like this:

```html
<div class="info">
<ul class="info-fields">
<li style="display: none">
<span style="display:none" itemprop="brand">Text</span></li>
<li>Name: <h1 style="font-size: 14px;margin: 0px;display: inline;"><strong>Demo</strong></h1></li>
<li>Genre: <a href="url">text 1</a>, <a href="url">text 2</a></li>
<li>Country: <a href="url">text 3</a>, <a href="url">text 4</a></li>
<li>Duration: 02:53</li>
<li>Studio: <a href="url">Disney</a></li>
<li>Models: <a href="url" >text 5</a>, <a href="url">text 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How to get it < a href="url">text 1, < a href="url">text 2< /a>

Thanks

```
<li>Genre: <a href="url">text 1</a>, <a href="url">text 2</a></li>
```

My code

```
  $tagss = $html->find('ul.info-fields li:nth-child(3) a');
  $args_tags = array();   
  foreach($tagss as $element)
  {
     $tag1 = $element->plaintext;
     array_push($args_tags, $tag1);
   }
```

Comment: I've edited....

Comment: well your `ul` class is wrong `filminfo-fields` should be `info-fields` based on the html

Comment: Sorry I write wrong, I have revised info-fields but it gets all  card <a> in info-fields

Comment: So what are you getting currently? the whole li?

Comment: simple-html-dom doesn't understand nth-child. You might want to switch to [this one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom).

Comment: Yes..................

Answer (score 0):

If your url is a variable try:

```
<li>Genre: <a href="<?=$url1?>">text 1</a>, <a href="<?=$url2?>">text 2</a></li>
```